# Ctrl+click doesn't work in Eclipse Luna on OS X Yosemite

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, osx-yosemite

I read some answers for "click+ctrl is not working" and it seems that all of solutions are for Windows, however I got this issue on OSX Yosemite.

I just checkout the project form SVN, but I found I can't access any destination of a class by ctr+click. I tried to import the project as a new Java project, but I still can not find the destination for some class...any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when sources are not compiled because of project misconfiguration. Try Project>Clean. Also try F3 which is shortcut for CTRL+click.

Comment: thx for your answer , but I got an error "your resouce is not on the build path of a Java Project" when I try fn+F3

Comment: ok, I guess you copy-pasted some source into Eclipse, apparently this source has a dependency on 3rd party jar, so you need to put this jar in the build path, do you how to do that? Also do have the missing jar.

Comment: yes , we manage the jars with maven , but I already use "mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -P dev -U" get the jars....but it doesn't work >_<

Comment: In this case you must add the dependency. What is the fully qualifies name of the class you are missing.